# Fast index creation issue

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, mysql-5.6

One thing that I can't explain is creating secondary index that doesn't trigger fast index creation as it should. I noticed that while creating secondary index on larger table, it gets actually recreated (state: copy to tmp table) instead of just appending the new index. This takes more than 1 hour.

Some data about DB and specific table;

- MySQL version: 5.6.23
- Engine: InnoDB
- Table size: +25 mil rows, 16
  columns, +8GB overall size

SQL statement:

```
CREATE INDEX secindex ON table_name (col3,col4,col5);
```

If I alter table before creating index, fast index creation is executed (not the whole table is recreated). Create index statement is executed in 2 minutes.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name FORCE;
OPTIMIZE TABLE table_name;
DUMP table and import back
```

Interestingly altering with the query mentioned below indexing procedure doesn't change and the whole table is copied again.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I can assume it has to do something with data fragmentation but I couldn't find any straightforward answer to that. I would be very thankful if someone could pinpoint me to what metrics should I check or explanation of how engine decides how this is going to be executed.

Comment: is this could be one of reasons for Your problem - InnoDB tables created before MySQL 5.6 do not support ALTER TABLE ... ALGORITHM=INPLACE for tables that include temporal columns (DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP) and have not been rebuilt ?

Comment: @a_vlad while this could be possible, sadly is not.  

Table was re-created 8 months ago and MySQL 5.6 was already in place.   Also this would mean that after executing query:  

`ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;`  that also recreates table. Fast index creation would take place but it does not.

Comment: Please show the entire CREATE TABLE. Are you using compound primary key?